# Run time error 1004. Method 'Range' object '_Global' _ failed

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

When I run my program only for one line (instead of variable i, put any other number) of the worksheet, there's no problem. But when I tried to do it for other lines using a FOR loop, the error message  appears `Run time error 1004. Method 'Range' object '_Global' _ failed`. The debugger always highlights the 14th line. But I don't know if I have to fix just this line. Hope anyone can help me...my code is below.

```
Sub depth()
    Dim VAR1 As Double
    Dim VAR2 As Double
    Dim VAR3 As Double
    Dim finalDepth As Double
    Dim i As Integer

  ' Calculation of depth when soil temperature is zero. Calculation 
  ' was made considering linear change of temperature between 2 values

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        For i = 2 To 30547

          ' (PART HIGHLIGHTED BY DEBUGGER)

            If Range("Fi").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Gi").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Hi").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Ii").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Ji").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Ki").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Li").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Mi").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Ni").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Oi").Value > 0 And _
                Range("Pi").Value > 0 Or _
                Range("Fi").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Gi").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Hi").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Ii").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Ji").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Ki").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Li").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Mi").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Ni").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Oi").Value < 0 And _
                Range("Pi").Value < 0 Then

                Range("Ri").Value = 0

          ' Calculation of depth when temperature is zero for each column on one row

            ElseIf (Range("Fi").Value > 0 And Range("Gi").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Fi") - Range("Gi"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("G1") - Range("F1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Fi") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("F1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth

          ' Columns g and h

            ElseIf (Range("Gi").Value > 0 And Range("Hi").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Gi") - Range("Hi"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("H1") - Range("G1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Gi") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("G1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth

          ' Columns h and i

            ElseIf (Range("Hi").Value > 0 And Range("Ii").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Hi") - Range("Ii"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("I1") - Range("H1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Hi") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("H1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth

          ' Columns i and j

            ElseIf (Range("Ii").Value > 0 And Range("Ji").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Ii") - Range("Ji"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("J1") - Range("I1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Ii") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("I1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth

          ' Columns j and k

            ElseIf (Range("Ji").Value > 0 And Range("Ki").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Ji") - Range("Ki"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("K1") - Range("J1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Ji") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("J1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth

          ' Columns k and l

            ElseIf (Range("Ki").Value > 0 And Range("Li").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Ki") - Range("Li"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("L1") - Range("K1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Ki") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("K1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth

          ' Columns l and m

            ElseIf (Range("Li").Value > 0 And Range("Mi").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Li") - Range("Mi"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("M1") - Range("L1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Li") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("L1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth

          ' Columns m and n

            ElseIf (Range("Mi").Value > 0 And Range("Ni").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Mi") - Range("Ni"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("N1") - Range("M1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Mi") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("M1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth

          ' Columns n and o

            ElseIf (Range("Ni").Value > 0 And Range("Oi").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Ni") - Range("Oi"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("O1") - Range("N1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Ni") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("N1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth

          ' Column o and p

            ElseIf (Range("Oi").Value > 0 And Range("Pi").Value < 0) Then
                VAR1 = (Range("Oi") - Range("Pi"))
                VAR2 = VAR1 / (Range("P1") - Range("O1"))
                VAR3 = Range("Oi") / VAR2
                finalDepth = Range("O1") + VAR3
                Range("Ri").Value = finalDepth
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Do Range("F" & i).Value` , etc.

Comment: ...and add parentheses `()` around each group of `And` tests.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a period before all the Range calls

```
.Range("F" & i).Value
```